# understanding what the end result is for document.submit

Tags: javascript, submit, document

Is there a way to find out the destination of the information or track where it goes when form instance information is created from document.submit? 
I have to reverse engineer this application that is taking form submissions but I am having difficulty trying to find out where it's going.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a modern web browser, like Chrome, you can use the network developer tools within to help you.

You can access the Chrome developer tools with the F12 key and also Ctrl+Shift+i and then go to the network tab. [network tools example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMCaY.png). There you will be able to click on individual requests and see the request headers and response data, along with any other relevant data.